# Is it possible to jump not over to '.next()' item in jQuery, element next to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to reinvent a wheel with a archive list, got this so far

[jsfiddle link to source code](http://jsfiddle.net/umren/cMG4g/)

what i'am trying to do:

when u press arrow button, it hide a logical element next to it.

1) arrow left to year must hide everying inside this year (except number of year)
2) arrow next to month must hide everything in this month (except number of month)
3) if i create more years - they must not interfere

possible solution would be something like .next().next() or next(2) to jump over the next element.. but that's not working in jquery!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution is to jump up to the `.parent()` and then hiding/showing the list `.next()` to it. Like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $('.toggle-year,.toggle-month').toggle(
        function() {
            $(this).html('&#9660;');
            $(this).parent().next().hide();

        },

        function() {
            $(this).html('&#9658;');
            $(this).parent().next().show();

        }
    );
});
```

Check this fiddle to see if this is the behavior you want: http://jsfiddle.net/LV6VK/

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `.parent()` function and then use the `.find()` function with an id or a class to specify which element you need.
And using `.next().next()` does work.